# ScrollView Inside FlatList Height Issue in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, scrollview

**I'm encountering a region issue when I use a ScrollView within a FlatList in my React Native application**

It appears that you have a React Native application with a ProductView component that contains a FlatList inside a ScrollView. The FlatList renders items using a CellRenderer component, and it seems like you're trying to implement paging with horizontal scrolling.

I have a large dataset, but I'm facing an issue with the height where some of the data is being cut off on a single screen. Can you please check this problem?

```
`const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const CellRenderer = ({
  item,
  numberArray,
  shareID,
  handleLeftSwipe,
  handleRightSwipe,
  navigation,
}) => {
  const [division, setIsDivision] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const isLogin = useSelector(state => state.reducer.isLoggedIn);
  const verify = useSelector(state => state.reducer.verify);
  const [imageStates, setImageStates] = useState(false);
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const HandelScreenShot = async () => {
    try {
      const ScreenUrl = await captureScreen({
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 0.8,
      });
      const saveScreen = await CameraRoll.save(ScreenUrl, {type: 'photo'});
      console.log('Image saved to camera roll:', saveScreen);
      Alert.alert('', 'ScreenShot Capture !!');
    } catch (error) {
      //console.error('Failed to save image to camera roll:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Contact');
  };
  const handleOfferNavigation = offerId => {
    navigation.navigate('GetProduct', {offerId});
    console.log(offerId, '==============?');
  };
  const generateLink = async () => {
    try {
      const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
        link: `https://www.albia.in/jTpts?id=${shareID}`,

        domainUriPrefix: 'https://albiabiocareurl.page.link',
        analytics: {
          campaign: 'banner',
        },
        android: {
          packageName: 'com.albiaapp',
        },
      });
      console.log(link, 'linkishere');
      return link;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating dynamic link:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleShare = async () => {
    const getLink = await generateLink();
    // const title = item?.brand_name;
    try {
      Share.share({
        // title:title,
        message: getLink,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkImage = item.visual_image;

    setImageStates(checkImage);
    const hasDivision = item.product_division?.some(element =>
      numberArray?.includes(element.id),
    );
    //  console.log(hasDivision,'hasDivision')
    setIsDivision(hasDivision);
  }, [item, numberArray]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.body} key={item.id}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       //data
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const ProductView = ({navigation}) => {
  const verify = useSelector(state => state.reducer.verify);
  // console.log(verify, 'verify');

  // const viewRef = useRef(null);
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);
  const getDiv = useSelector(state => state.reducerDiv.divId);
  const getSelectDivAll = useSelector(state => state.reducerDiv.divApi);
  const numberArray = getSelectDivAll
    ? getSelectDivAll?.map(str => parseInt(str))
    : [];
  // console.log(numberArray, '------2');

  //const [itemData, setItemData] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [shareID, setShareID] = useState(0);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [renderedData, setRenderedData] = useState([]);

  console.log(shareID, 'hii');

  const route = useRoute();
  const id = route.params?.id;
  const {filteredData} = route.params;

  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <CellRenderer
      item={item}
      numberArray={numberArray}
      shareID={shareID}
      navigation={navigation}
    />
  );
  const itemIndex = filteredData.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
  // console.log(itemIndex);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      setCurrentIndex(itemIndex);
    }
  }, [itemIndex]);

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
        {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#000000" />}
      </View>
    );
  };
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({viewableItems}) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      const firstVisibleItem = viewableItems[0];
      const itemId = firstVisibleItem?.item?.id;
      // Do something with the itemId (e.g., store it in state)
      console.log('Currently displayed item ID:', itemId);
      setShareID(itemId);
    }
  });
 

  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
    waitForInteraction: true,
    minimumViewTime: 1,
  });
  return (
    <LinearGradient
      // ref={viewRef}
      colors={['#7ABF49', '#13A15D']}
      start={{x: 0.99, y: 0}}
      end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
      style={[styles.linearGradient]}>
      <HeaderItem navigation={navigation} />
      
      <ScrollView horizontal={false}>
        <FlatList
          //  ref={flatListRef}
          data={filteredData}
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={100}
          contentOffset={{
            x: currentIndex * SCREEN_WIDTH,
            y: 0,
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig.current}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current}
          //onEndReached={loadMoreData}
          ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
          initialNumToRender={30} // Render 10 items initially
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: SCREEN_WIDTH, // Width of each item
            offset: SCREEN_HEIGHT * index, // Offset for each item
            index,
          })}
          windowSize={30} // Render 30 items outside the visible area
          removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window
          //updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
          // snapToInterval={300}
          // decelerationRate="fast"
        />
      </ScrollView>
      
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  linearGradient: {
    // flex: 1,
    // backgroundColor:'#ffff'
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffff',
    //flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    borderTopStartRadius: 40,
    borderTopEndRadius: 40,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    //height: SCREEN_HEIGHT +200,
     flexGrow:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  cardItem: {
    width: '48%',
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingBottom: 15,
  },
  productImg: {
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 20,

    height: 220,
  },
 

});
export default ProductView;`
```